# Unable to make ROS2 package (but used to be able to)

Tags: c++, package, ros2, colcon

I am having trouble making a ros2 package for the Robotis Open manipulator. I was able to run this and am able to run this on a virtual machine, but my main machine is now not able to build these packages anymore. I have reinstall foxy a number of times and the results are still the same.

These are the commands I am using:

```
colcon build --event-handlers console_direct+ --cmake-args -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON --packages-select dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces
```

Although a simple colcon build also gives me the same errors I wanted to see if making it verbose would help me identify the issue.

Here are the results I got:

```
Starting >>> dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.4.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found ament_cmake: 0.9.9 (/opt/ros/foxy/share/ament_cmake/cmake)
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python3 (found suitable version "3.8.10", minimum required is "3")
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python3
-- Found builtin_interfaces: 1.0.0 (/opt/ros/foxy/share/builtin_interfaces/cmake)
-- Using all available rosidl_typesupport_c: rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_c;rosidl_typesupport_introspection_c
-- Found rosidl_adapter: 1.2.1 (/opt/ros/foxy/share/rosidl_adapter/cmake)
-- Found OpenSSL: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so (found version "1.1.1f")
-- Found FastRTPS: /opt/ros/foxy/include
-- Using all available rosidl_typesupport_cpp: rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_cpp;rosidl_typesupport_introspection_cpp
-- Found rosidl_default_generators: 1.0.1 (/opt/ros/foxy/share/rosidl_default_generators/cmake)
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python3 (found version "3.8.10")
-- Found ament_cmake_ros: 0.9.2 (/opt/ros/foxy/share/ament_cmake_ros/cmake)
-- Using all available rosidl_typesupport_c: rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_c;rosidl_typesupport_introspection_c
-- Using all available rosidl_typesupport_cpp: rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_cpp;rosidl_typesupport_introspection_cpp
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python3 (found suitable version "3.8.10", minimum required is "3.5")
-- Found python_cmake_module: 0.8.1 (/opt/ros/foxy/share/python_cmake_module/cmake)
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so (found suitable version "3.8.10", minimum required is "3.5")
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python3
-- Using PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS: /usr/include/python3.8
-- Using PYTHON_LIBRARIES: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so
-- Found PythonExtra: .so
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/mainuser/colcon_ws/build/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces
/usr/bin/cmake -S/home/mainuser/colcon_ws/src/DynamixelSDK/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces -B/home/mainuser/colcon_ws/build/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/mainuser/colcon_ws/build/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces/CMakeFiles /home/mainuser/colcon_ws/build/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces//CMakeFiles/progress.marks
/usr/bin/make  -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/mainuser/colcon_ws/build/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces'
/usr/bin/make  -f CMakeFiles/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces__cpp.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces__cpp.dir/depend
/usr/bin/make  -f CMakeFiles/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces__rosidl_generator_c.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces__rosidl_generator_c.dir/depend
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces__py/CMakeFiles/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces__py.dir/all', needed by 'CMakeFiles/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces__python.dir/all'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/mainuser/colcon_ws/build/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces'
cd /home/mainuser/colcon_ws/build/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/mainuser/colcon_ws/src/DynamixelSDK/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces /home/mainuser/colcon_ws/src/DynamixelSDK/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces /home/mainuser/colcon_ws/build/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces /home/mainuser/colcon_ws/build/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces /home/mainuser/colcon_ws/build/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces/CMakeFiles/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces__cpp.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/mainuser/colcon_ws/build/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces'
[  2%] Generating C code for ROS interfaces
/usr/bin/python3 /opt/ros/foxy/share/rosidl_generator_c/cmake/../../../lib/rosidl_generator_c/rosidl_generator_c --generator-arguments-file /home/mainuser/colcon_ws/build/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces/rosidl_generator_c__arguments.json
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/mainuser/colcon_ws/build/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces'
/usr/bin/make  -f CMakeFiles/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces__cpp.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces__cpp.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/mainuser/colcon_ws/build/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces'
[  5%] Generating C++ code for ROS interfaces
/usr/bin/python3 /opt/ros/foxy/share/rosidl_generator_cpp/cmake/../../../lib/rosidl_generator_cpp/rosidl_generator_cpp --generator-arguments-file /home/mainuser/colcon_ws/build/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces/rosidl_generator_cpp__arguments.json
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/mainuser/colcon_ws/build/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces'
[  5%] Built target dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces__cpp
cd /home/mainuser/colcon_ws/build/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/mainuser/colcon_ws/src/DynamixelSDK/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces /home/mainuser/colcon_ws/src/DynamixelSDK/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces /home/mainuser/colcon_ws/build/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces /home/mainuser/colcon_ws/build/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces /home/mainuser/colcon_ws/build/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces/CMakeFiles/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces__rosidl_generator_c.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/mainuser/colcon_ws/build/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces'
/usr/bin/make  -f CMakeFiles/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces__rosidl_generator_c.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces__rosidl_generator_c.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/mainuser/colcon_ws/build/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces'
[ 10%] Building C object CMakeFiles/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces__rosidl_generator_c.dir/rosidl_generator_c/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces/srv/detail/get_position__functions.c.o
[ 10%] Building C object CMakeFiles/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces__rosidl_generator_c.dir/rosidl_generator_c/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces/msg/detail/set_position__functions.c.o
/usr/bin/cc -DRCUTILS_ENABLE_FAULT_INJECTION -DROS_PACKAGE_NAME=\"dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces\" -Ddynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces__rosidl_generator_c_EXPORTS -I/home/mainuser/colcon_ws/build/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces/rosidl_generator_c -isystem /opt/ros/foxy/include -fPIC -Wall -std=gnu11 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces__rosidl_generator_c.dir/rosidl_generator_c/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces/msg/detail/set_position__functions.c.o -MF CMakeFiles/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces__rosidl_generator_c.dir/rosidl_generator_c/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces/msg/detail/set_position__functions.c.o.d -o CMakeFiles/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces__rosidl_generator_c.dir/rosidl_generator_c/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces/msg/detail/set_position__functions.c.o -c /home/mainuser/colcon_ws/build/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces/rosidl_generator_c/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces/msg/detail/set_position__functions.c
/usr/bin/cc -DRCUTILS_ENABLE_FAULT_INJECTION -DROS_PACKAGE_NAME=\"dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces\" -Ddynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces__rosidl_generator_c_EXPORTS -I/home/mainuser/colcon_ws/build/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces/rosidl_generator_c -isystem /opt/ros/foxy/include -fPIC -Wall -std=gnu11 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces__rosidl_generator_c.dir/rosidl_generator_c/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces/srv/detail/get_position__functions.c.o -MF CMakeFiles/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces__rosidl_generator_c.dir/rosidl_generator_c/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces/srv/detail/get_position__functions.c.o.d -o CMakeFiles/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces__rosidl_generator_c.dir/rosidl_generator_c/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces/srv/detail/get_position__functions.c.o -c /home/mainuser/colcon_ws/build/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces/rosidl_generator_c/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces/srv/detail/get_position__functions.c
[ 12%] Linking C shared library libdynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces__rosidl_generator_c.so
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces__rosidl_generator_c.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc -fPIC -shared -Wl,-soname,libdynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces__rosidl_generator_c.so -o libdynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces__rosidl_generator_c.so CMakeFiles/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces__rosidl_generator_c.dir/rosidl_generator_c/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces/msg/detail/set_position__functions.c.o CMakeFiles/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces__rosidl_generator_c.dir/rosidl_generator_c/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces/srv/detail/get_position__functions.c.o  -Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/foxy/lib: /opt/ros/foxy/lib/libbuiltin_interfaces__rosidl_typesupport_introspection_c.so /opt/ros/foxy/lib/libbuiltin_interfaces__rosidl_typesupport_c.so /opt/ros/foxy/lib/libbuiltin_interfaces__rosidl_typesupport_introspection_cpp.so /opt/ros/foxy/lib/libbuiltin_interfaces__rosidl_typesupport_cpp.so /opt/ros/foxy/lib/libbuiltin_interfaces__rosidl_generator_c.so /opt/ros/foxy/lib/librosidl_typesupport_introspection_cpp.so /opt/ros/foxy/lib/librosidl_typesupport_introspection_c.so /opt/ros/foxy/lib/librosidl_typesupport_cpp.so /opt/ros/foxy/lib/librosidl_typesupport_c.so /opt/ros/foxy/lib/librosidl_runtime_c.so /opt/ros/foxy/lib/librcpputils.so /opt/ros/foxy/lib/librcutils.so -ldl
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/mainuser/colcon_ws/build/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces'
[ 12%] Built target dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces__rosidl_generator_c
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/mainuser/colcon_ws/build/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces'
make: *** [Makefile:149: all] Error 2
--- stderr: dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces__py/CMakeFiles/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces__py.dir/all', needed by 'CMakeFiles/dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces__python.dir/all'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [Makefile:149: all] Error 2
---
Failed   <<< dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces [1.42s, exited with code 2]

Summary: 0 packages finished [1.63s]
  1 package failed: dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces
  1 package had stderr output: dynamixel_sdk_custom_interfaces
```

This used to work for me as I mentioned above. I attempted to debug my ros2 packages in visual code and might have altered some settings (I don't remember editing system settings though, just settings in visual code) but either way, it was working, but now isn't and I can't think of anything that caused it or a way to solve it. Any help would be appreciated. The only solution I see now is reinstalling the operating system which I would prefer not to at this point.

Comment: It may make sense to ask this question or questions like it on the Robotics Stack Exchange or [ROS Answers](https://answers.ros.org)
Some items to include when seeking similar assistance include your current operating system / platform version, which ROS version you're using, and how you installed it? (ROS repos, built from source, etc).